# iwconfig - /proc/net/wireless does not exist

Tags: ubuntu, wireless, ifconfig, iwconfig

I am trying to use `iwconfig` to get info about `wlan0`. When I try I get:

```
wlan0     no wireless extensions.
```

`ifconfig` seems to printout normally (includes an ip address for the connection). The machine appears to have *Wireless Extensions v22* installed, but `iwconfig --version` says:

```
iwconfig  Wireless-Tools version 30
      Compatible with Wireless Extension v11 to v22.

Cannot read /proc/net/wireless
```

Upon further inspection, `/proc/net/wireless` does not exist but `/proc/net/dev` does. I can't figure out why `iwconfig` does not work and/or doesn't create the file. The connection exists and I am able to get on the internet with the machine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I fixed the problem.

I rebuilt my kernel. Before rebuilding I called `make menuconfig` to manually set kernel parameters. I told it to include **cfg80211 wireless extensions compatibility** under the **Networking support - Wireless** menu. After installing the new image it worked perfectly.

Comment: +1, I can confirm this is the way to go. Seems like the 'wireless extensions compatibility' option is not standard (anymore?).